# If $|z| < 1 $ , calculate $ s= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 \cdot z^n $

Tags: calculus

As far as I understand we should try to find a geometric series $g(z)$ with a known sum and then get the sum $s$ from manipulating $g(z)$. I have a hard time finding $g(z)$ though. Any help appreciated!

Comment: differentiation on it yes. ah i see what you mean now. yep remember them both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a geometric series we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{z}{1-z} ,
\end{eqnarray*}
differentiate and multiply by $z$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n z^n = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} ,
\end{eqnarray*}
differentiate and multiply by $z$ again
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 z^n = \frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3} .
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** $n^2=n(n-1)+n$

**Hint 2:** consider first and second derivatives of geometric series.

Comment: I upvoted your hint 1, though I doubt it is helpful to the OP as such.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{#C00}{n^2}x^n=x^2\,\overbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{#C00}{n(n-1)}x^{n-2}}^{\frac2{(1-x)^3}}+x\,\overbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{#C00}{n}x^{n-1}}^{\frac1{(1-x)^2}}$$